How to handle fragment business logic while using AndroidView composable
@Composable
fun ReaderContent(fragmenFactory: FragmentFactory){
    AndroidView(
        factory = {context->
            FragmentContainerView(context).apply {
                id = View.generateViewId()
                val fragmentManager = (context as FragmentActivity).supportFragmentManager
                fragmentManager.fragmentFactory = fragmenFactory
                val fragment = fragmentManager.fragmentFactory.instantiate(
                    context.classLoader,
                    EpubNavigatorFragment::class.java.name
                )
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(id,fragment)
                    .commit()
            }
        },
        update = {fragment ->
            fragment.getFragment<EpubNavigatorFragment>().currentLocator
        }
    )
}

i am creating an ebook reader app, above is some basic code of EpubNavigatorFragment  which hold complete logic and expose some method or properties like currentLocator: Stateflow<Locator>  (provides the current location in ebook). I am having trouble in integrating that business logic with my viewmodel, passing everything from composable to viewmodel seems composable is handling major business logic. In a nutshell how can i handle that, what's the best practices of handling such situation while implementing a third party fragment
someone suggested me to give up on this and implement my own reader logic using a parsing library and webview but the current library already provides a lot of things out of the box making me hesitant to code everything myself moreover this is my first app so i want to keep things simple

So first, talking about best practices of working with Fragments in Compose
A great video on how to work with Fragments in Compose, just dropped on the official Android youtube channel here
I think you should watch that once, you'll have a lot of options to explore going forward
However, for your case, I'd definitely go with re-writing the logic with the webview and custom parsing, because if you go hacking at the very beginning with features, you will keep multiplying them. But for the purpose of this question now,
Depend on the latest Fragment Compose dependency, like so
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-compose:$fragment_version"

Once you're done, you can simply wrap your EpubNavigatorFragment with the AndroidFragment class and you're good to go. No need of the above AndroidView handling
// Adds an existing Fragment to your composable
AndroidFragment<EpubNavigatorFragment>()

If you want more fine grained control over the Fragment instance, you can do something like this as well
AndroidFragment<EpubNavigatorFragment>(){ fragment ->
 // Do something with the fragment
}

There's a host of other functions and usages possible, which you can see here and the above video obviously
Hope this helps you!
Second, talking about passing everything from your composable to your view model, doesn't look ideal, but when you inter-op with the XML views, there are some hacks like this that happen
However, to prevent something like this, you can instantiate your view model with all the arguments that you receive in your Fragment like that locator flow that you're talking about, using a ViewModelFactory just once. After that you can continue with whatever you want in your View Model. That's what you'd have done in an XML based app as well

Thanx for the respone but i did saw that view video and read documentation  of the same earlier, but there is a thing that the fragment uses factory method for instantiation. Moreover AndroidFragment composable also uses AndroidView under the hood well i wasn't able to understand the whole thing that's why i used AndroidView, for the approach as a whole (using fragment) was also motivated by the chance of getting to know the fragments

But did it solve your problem?

no it didn't as i said the fragment i want to use utilise factory approach where as AndroidFragment uses bundle to pass argument.

I'm afraid you won't be able to do that

i see then could you help me in suggesting a library for epub parsing would prefer one with documentation and ease of integrability with compose most of them either don't have documentation or pretty rusty. I don't want to abandon it :/

Getting support for compose is tough maybe if they're old. Inter-op is not a problem, trust me, you can go ahead with this

can i discuss this with you via linkedIn won't take much long(5min) as commenting here creates a gap
